# FTP Upload/Download in C# using WININET functions with progress bar

Tags: c#, ftp, progress-bar, wininet

So I found this really nice [ftp library](http://ftplib.codeplex.com/) that seems to do most of the stuff with WININET functions just fine except one single thing. It doesn't show progress of uploading/downloading files. Is there an easy way to fix this? Or this is like hell to expand it and I would be better off with `WebRequest` and other libraries (I've seen code examples for progress bar there but this clean and nice library seems to be nice to me so I would prefer to use this one).

Also if I go with WebRequests or similar will it be as good in terms of speed, scalability etc as using Wininet?

```
    public void GetFile(string remoteFile, string localFile, bool failIfExists)
    {
        int ret = WININET.FtpGetFile(_hConnect,
             remoteFile,
             localFile,
             failIfExists,
             WINAPI.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
             WININET.FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY,
             IntPtr.Zero);

        if (ret == 0)
        {
            Error();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not direct answer to my question but http://netftp.codeplex.com/ does all I need and even more.